# How to get rid of error in slice for bootstrap estimates and find standard error

Tags: r

I made bootstrap estimates to find the standard error. I made a logit regression (not shown here), and I'm using that code aka logit, but for some reason, there is a slice error even though I'm not using slice() at all. Please help.

```
M<-500
bootstrap_results<-rep(0,500)
hold<- rep(0, length(bootstrap_results))
for(i in 1:length(bootstrap_results)){
  sample<-sample_n(data=mroz, size=nrow(mroz), replace=TRUE)
  logit <- glm(inlf ~ nwifeinc + educ + age + exper +
                 kidsge6 + kidslt6 +unem+ city,
               data = sample, family = binomial(link="logit"))
  X <- sample %>% select(nwifeinc, educ, age, exper, kidslt6, kidsge6, unem, city)
  ones <- rep(1, nrow(X))
  X <- cbind(ones, X)
    X_means <- colMeans(X)
  betas <- logit$coefficients
  linear_part <- X_means %*% betas
  PEA <- logit$coefficients[2] * (exp(linear_part)/((1 + exp(linear_part))^2))
  bootstrap_results[i]<- PEA
}
```

I keep getting :

```
  argument "tbl" is missing, with no default
```

I also need to find the standard error, but it keeps giving me 0:
`bse<-sd(bootstrap_results)`

Comment: Hi Sarah, please provide a `dput()` of your data in order to reproduce.

Comment: Hi, I dont know what that means, or how to do that.

Comment: Run `dput(mroz)` and paste the output. If it's a large data file, only use a small portion.

Comment: Change `sample<-sample_n(data=mroz, size=nrow(mroz), replace=TRUE)` to `sample<-sample_n(tbl=mroz, size=nrow(mroz), replace=TRUE)`

Comment: OH that worked! thanks so much!